# Can I have entities that connect to a different databases in OpenXava?

Tags: postgresql, firebird, openxava

I am starting to develop OpenXava apps to replace an old system (Delphi programs using a Firebird database), but the new apps will have Postgres as the data store.

The app I am developing now needs to have read-only access to 2 tables from the old Firebird database (thus not modifying them whatsoever!) and everything else will be in the new Postgres database (basically, 2 entities from one database and about 4 from another).

Eventually everything will be moved to Postgres, but while the integration is happening, I need to be doing things like these.

Is there a way to do this in OpenXava? Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider doing it via PostgreSQL, using a foreign data wrapper like `odbc_fdw`. So to the application it looks like they're just PostgreSQL tables, and behind the scenes PostgreSQL fetches the data from Firebird.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a second persistence-unit in your persistence.xml against your old database, then when you need to access to the old database use the JPA syntaxt instead of XPersistence.getManager() to get a manager against your old database, thus:

```
EntityManagerFactory f = 
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("firebird");
EntityManager manager = f.createEntityManager();  
manager.getTransaction().begin();  

// Your code

manager.getTransaction().commit();  
manager.close();  // You have to close
```